# C# Splitting same line into 2 strings?

Tags: c#

I am making a project, But i need to be able to split 1 row of text into 2 strings.
How would i go about doing this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Stinger";
            Console.Write("Configuration FIle.... ");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\Stinger\Configuration\config.cfg"))
        {
            Console.Write("Found");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            Console.WriteLine("\r\n");

            Console.WriteLine("--Configuration--");

            string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Stinger\Configuration\config.cfg");
            foreach (string s in readText)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

        }
        else // Configuration File Else Statement
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Missing");
            Thread.Sleep(4000);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my Config Contents

```
fullscreen 1
```

I want to be able to make "fullscreen" and "1" part of the row 2 strings.
I've done continuous googling and reading articles on how to split.
But it's not making any sense to me.
Any help?

Comment: Have you tried `string[] splitted = s.Split(" ")`?

Comment: Why continuous googleing? a simple search will give you lots of suggestions [use this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=split+string+c%23&oq=split+string+c%23&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.6503j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: A simple google search with "c# string split" will reveal everything

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple [string.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) and is actually very straightforward and fundamental.

Assuming this is the code where you are getting `fullscreen 1` from, you can do something like this.

```
            string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Stinger\Configuration\config.cfg");
            foreach (string s in readText)
            {
                string[] split= s.Split(" ");
                Console.WriteLine(split[0]+" "+split[1]);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
```

The `Console.WriteLine` will print your expected output.